# Methods to find the spectrum of an operator

Tags: operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, markov-chains, semigroups-of-operators

Suppose we have a bounded, self-adjoint operator $T$ on a set of functions $\mathcal{F}$. What kinds of methods are there to find the spectrum of $T$?

Here is the setting I'm wondering about: consider a Markov process $X_t$, and suppose $P_t$ is the Markov semigroup which acts on measures $\mu(x)$ in the state space. The spectrum of $P_t$ relates to the rate of convergence of $\mu(x)$ to the invariant measure, and we're usually interested in the spectral gap. However I don't know how one can find the spectrum (or bounds on it, or the spectral gap) in general.

If $X_t$ is a discrete Markov chain, and we know all the transition probabilities, then the eigenvalues can be computed for the matrix $T$. But I don't know how to study the continuous version, where instead of a transition matrix we have an operator on functions.

Comment: It's usually hard to compute the spectrum explicitly except in very special cases.  However there is a huge literature on ways to compute bounds.  *Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory* by E.B. Davies might be one place to start.

Comment: If you have an explicit form of the generator of the semigroup (e.g., the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator), then I think semigroup methods work (maybe hard sometimes), e.g., spectral mapping theorem.